Get formatted value from worksheet cell in ExcelJS
Is there a way to get the formatted numerical value from a worksheet cell in ExcelJS?  In the Excel workbook the cell formula results in value is 5.726027397260274, has a number format of "#,###.0" , and displays as "5.7".
But in Excel JS, workbook.getWorksheet("slide1").getCell('Q4').text returns "5.726027397260274".  Does ExcelJS have a way to resolve number formats to retrieve formatted values?

{
 text: "5.726027397260274",
  _value:   {
    "model": {
        "address": "Q4",
        "value": 5.726027397260274,
        "type": 2,
        "style": {
            "numFmt": "#,##0.0",
            "font": {
                "size": 11,
                "color": {
                    "theme": 1
                },
                "name": "Calibri",
                "family": 2,
                "scheme": "minor"
            },
            "border": {
                "left": {
                    "style": "thin",
                    "color": {
                        "indexed": 64
                    }
                },
                "right": {
                    "style": "thin",
                    "color": {
                        "indexed": 64
                    }
                },
                "top": {
                    "style": "thin",
                    "color": {
                        "indexed": 64
                    }
                },
                "bottom": {
                    "style": "thin",
                    "color": {
                        "indexed": 64
                    }
                }
            },
            "fill": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern": "solid",
                "fgColor": {
                    "argb": "FFFFFF00"
                },
                "bgColor": {
                    "indexed": 64
                }
            },
            "alignment": {
                "horizontal": "center"
            }
        }
        
    }
  }
}


doesn't seem to have that option... see alternative: w formatted text (if applicable) https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#cell-object
